# Can you configure Cypress to log requests and responses to a file?

Tags: cypress

When I run my Cypress tests I randomly get HTTP 405 Method not allowed code when I submit the form, but the HTTP method is a correct one - POST. If I open the Developer Tools to see the outgoing request the HTTP 405 is never returned, in other words the error only happens when Developer Tools are closed. No combination of `cy.pause()`, `cy.wait()` alleviates the problem.

**Question:** Can you configure Cypress so it logs all the outgoing requests and responses to a file so I don't have to open DevTools?

Answer (score 3):

Should be possible with `cy.intercept()` functional handler.

General info here [Using the routeHandler function](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Using-the-routeHandler-function)

```js
cy.intercept(url, (req) => {
  cy.writeFile('my-log', req, { flag: 'a' })  // append
  req.continue((res) => {
    cy.writeFile('my-log', res, { flag: 'a' })  // append
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing an interceptor solely for logging purposes is not very efficient.

You can generate a [HAR](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/) file that includes detailed information about the network activity during the execution of your Cypress tests.

Especially for this purpose, you can use the [cypress-har-generator](https://github.com/NeuraLegion/cypress-har-generator).

```js
describe('my tests', () => {
  before(() => {
    // start recording
    cy.recordHar();
  });

  after(() => {
    // save the HAR file
    cy.saveHar({ waitForIdle: true });
  });

  it('does something', () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.com');

    // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain why it is not efficient? By efficient do you mean there is performance tag on it?

Comment: @Yoda Precisely, this plugin allows capturing requests/responses from the browser using [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) in the background, without any negative impact on test performance or memory usage, without interference to the flow.